# Angular 4 Zooming

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, jquery.panzoom

I am new to Angular 4 and trying to find a library for pan zooming.
I am not able to find any package on npm. I tried to add jquery in my project, then added jquery.panzoom, but because jquery.panzoom is written in JavaScript and my angular project is in TypeScript there is no @types for jquery.panzoom so it is not working.

Steps i followed

1) npm install --save jquery

2) npm install --save @types/jquery

3) import * as $ from 'jquery';

```
   //till here jquery works fine
    $('.sample').click(function () {
      alert('div clicked.');
    });
```

3) npm install --save jquery.panzoom

```
   $('#panzoomDiv').panzoom(
      {
        $zoomIn: $('.zoom-in'),
        $zoomOut: $('.zoom-out'),
        $zoomRange: $('.zoom-range'),
        $reset: $('.reset')
      } 
    );
```

here i get the error

```
src/app/app.component.ts (22,22): Property 'panzoom' does not exist on type 
'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

then after going through [this](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc), i added

```
interface JQuery {
  panzoom(options: any): any;
}
```

to my typings.d.ts file.
Now it does compiles but gives this run time error

```
 ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery__(...).panzoom is not a function
at AppComponent.webpackJsonp.117.AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:22)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10848)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12349)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12288)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13149)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13090)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent_Host.html:1)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13075)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12255)
at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13475)
```

can someone please redirect me to a correct solution or a different zooming library.

Something like [this](http://openseadragon.github.io/)

**Update**

tried this approach, still doesn't work.

```
    <div style="display:block; padding: 10px;">
      <button id="btn-zoom-in-workspace"
              class="zoom-out">Zoom Out
      </button>
      <button id="btn-zoom-null-workspace"
              class="reset">Reset
      </button>
      <button id="btn-zoom-out-workspace"
              class="zoom-in">Zoom In
      </button>
      <input type="number" class="zoom-range">
   </div>
   <div id="panzoomDiv" #panzoomDiv>
   <div>

    import * as $ from 'jquery';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements  AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('panzoomDiv') panzoomDiv: ElementRef;
     ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (this.panzoomDiv)
           $(this.panzoomDiv.nativeElement).panzoom({
                $zoomIn: $('.zoom-in'),
                $zoomOut: $('.zoom-out'),
                $zoomRange: $('.zoom-range'),
                $reset: $('.reset')
        });
     }
  }
```

Comment: Where did you include the panzoom library?

Comment: types are not mandatory to use js in typescript you can use without it also

Comment: check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) on how to import third party js without types. hope it helps

Comment: @TheUnreal are you asking about importing panzoom? i did'nt imported panzoom because the code sample is $('something').panzoom();.

Comment: @TheUnreal should i import panzoom?, how should i go along with it?

Comment: Have you looked at hammer.js options?

Comment: You are just trying to use a library without even installing and importing its files...

Comment: @TheUnreal jquery.panzoom is a plugin of jquery, as shown <a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.panzoom">here</a> i am under the impression that i just have to import jquery using import * as $ from 'jquery' and then use jquery's object to access the method 'panzoom'. what is the right approach to this problem?

Comment: It's a plugin for jQuery. It's not jQuery. You need to import jquery and this plugin both!

Comment: @TheUnreal there is no exported module in jquery.panzoom. can you guide me how and what should i import?

Comment: @RahulSingh thank you for your article but i am having problem running the plugin of jquery, jquery alone is working just fine.

Comment: @aatishrana it should run fine. You should run all these after the DOM is created. In Angular terms in  ngAfterViewInit

Comment: @RahulSingh It is still giving the same error on ngAfterViewInit

Comment: @aatishrana you are using the class in jquery i would suggest you in afterview ininit make use of element refrence then it should work out, something like [this](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/FootBallScores/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @RahulSingh still same error.

Comment: can you update what have you tried

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153017/discussion-between-aatish-rana-and-rahul-singh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- npm install --save jquery
- Install jquery Panzoom

Add these to the scripts array of angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [ 
"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
"../node_modules/jquery.panzoom/dist/jquery.panzoom.min.js" 
],
```

In **template**

```
   <div style="display:block; padding: 10px;">
      <button id="btn-zoom-in-workspace"
              class="zoom-out" #reference>Zoom Out
      </button>
      <button id="btn-zoom-null-workspace"
              class="reset" #reference>Reset
      </button>
      <button id="btn-zoom-out-workspace"
              class="zoom-in" #reference>Zoom In
      </button>
      <input type="number" class="zoom-range">
   </div>
   <div id="panzoomDiv" #panzoomDiv>
   <div>
```

In the **component** use this

```
declare var $ : any;

@ViewChild('panzoomDiv') panzoomDiv: ElementRef;
//get all the other element references using elementref and use it in function below
     ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (this.panzoomDiv)
           $(this.panzoomDiv.nativeElement).panzoom({
                $zoomIn: $(#reference),
                $zoomOut: $(#reference),
                $zoomRange: $(#reference),
                $reset: $(#reference)
        });
     }
```